# lxml not being recognized in bs4: Python 3 on mac

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation, lxml

So, I have a mac on High Sierra and I am trying to import and use an [api](https://github.com/theriley106/Brickseek).  This is api is a python3 api and uses bs4, and specifically is using lxml within bs4 in order to parse a webpage.

However, I am having an issue getting bs4 to recognize that I have lxml installed on my machine.  I have installed both of them using pip, and both appear to have installed correctly.  I can write a program with ‘import bs4’ and ‘import lxml’ at the top and it compiles and runs perfectly fine.  However, no matter what I do I always get the following error when I run a program using this api.

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

On top of this, when I run the following code

```
import lxml
import bs4
print(bs4.builder.builder_registry.builders)
```

the output is

```
[<class 'bs4.builder._htmlparser.HTMLParserTreeBuilder'>]
```

With no lxml listed.

I have tried everything I have found on the various stack overflow threads related to this.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled both lxml and bs4 through various methods(pip, easy install, manually installing, homebrew).  I've manually linked lxml from brew.  And other things ive probably forgotten.  However I cant get it to work.

Anyone have any ideas/has anyone gone through this before.  Its possible I'm completely missing something small or stupid, since I've never messed with bs4 before, but I dont know.

Comment: Have you tried the macports version of lxml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the cause, but I had a similar case with a Flask app I'm working on. I worked around it by importing `bs4` locally in the function where I needed it.

One symptom I had was when I logged `bs4.builder.builder_registry.builders` at the top of my module, the logs ended up showing two entries: first with the proper builders and then with only HTML.